# Can I install Witcher 3 DLCs with external keys if the main game is on Steam?

Tags: steam, the-witcher-3

I've currently got the Witcher 3 main game on Steam and I'd like to install the two DLCs. Is it possible to purchase (legal) activation keys via a different website (given that games are often cheaper outside Steam) and to enter them via the "Activate a Product on Steam" box? I know that this is easy to do with standalone games, but I'd like to check that it works with DLCs as well.
Thanks!

Edit: I see that most websites sell GOG keys, which probably aren't compatible with Steam. Could I buy the GOTY edition on GOG and transfer the saves?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. Ensure that you own the base game on steam, and DLC keys will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly this with Dark Souls 3 and its expansions and it worked. So I guess for The Witcher 3 too.

> Could I buy the GOTY edition on GOG and transfer the saves?

The saves are saved in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\The Witcher 3\gamesaves\` ([Source](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Witcher_3:_Wild_Hunt#Save_game_data_location)), both when running the game from GOG and Steam. So yes you can and you don't even need to transfer the saves, they're already there.